# middleware.ts width nextauth and nextjs

Tags: next.js, next-auth

`I use next-auth.js with Credential as my login provider and Mongodb as my backend. To protect pages in next.js, I am trying to integrate next-auth.js with next.js middleware. Reference link

The issue I have is when the user is logged out, the middleware correctly routes to the login page. But after successful login, the user is redirected to the login page again. What am I missing?

```
middleware.ts

`export { default } from 'next-auth/middleware';
export const config = { matcher: ['/','/profile','/jadwal','/biodata','/learn'] };`


[...nextauth].ts

`import { compare } from 'bcryptjs';
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { connectToMongoDB } from '../../../lib/mongodb';
import User from '../../../models/user';
import { IUser } from '../../../types';

const options: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: "credentials",
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                await connectToMongoDB().catch(err => { throw new Error(err) })

                const user = await User.findOne({
                    email: credentials?.email
                }).select("+password")

                if (!user) {
                    throw new Error("Email dan password tidak ditemukan !")
                }

                const isPasswordCorrect = await compare(credentials!.password, user.password)

                if (!isPasswordCorrect) {
                    throw new Error("Email dan password tidak ditemukan !")
                }

                return user
            }
        })
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login"
    },
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt"
    },
    callbacks: {
        jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
            user && (token.user = user)
            return token
        },
        session: async ({ session, token }) => {
            const user = token.user as IUser
            session.user = user

            return session
        }
    }
}

export default NextAuth(options)
`
```

`i am using "next": "^13.2.4",
"next-auth": "^4.20.1",``

Answer (score 0):

> #### Specifying a [callbackUrl](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#specifying-a-callbackurl)
>
> The callbackUrl specifies to which URL the user will be redirected after signing in. **Defaults to the page URL the sign-in is initiated from**.

```js
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
//...
signIn("credentials", {
  email,
  password,
  callbackUrl: '/'
}
```

This will redirect the user to the `/` url after the signIn action.

Comment: I got this problem when after I deployed on vercel while on localhost there was no problem at all